# How to load image into a cell in QTableWidgets

Tags: c++, qt

i want to load a default image into all cell, but the image i want to load is always null, i don't know why. The image and .cpp are in the same place.

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
QBrush *brush = new QBrush();
QPixmap pixmap(QString("1.png"));
if (pixmap.isNull())
    std::cout << "isNull" << std::endl;
brush->setTexture(pixmap);
item->setBackground(*brush);
this->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem(*item));
```

[image]

Comment: Where is 1.png located on disk? It'll have to be in your working directory if you want to reference it like that.

Comment: "D:\Programmation\Git\Gomoku\src\core\1.png" AND "D:\Programmation\Git\Gomoku\src\core\GameEngine.cpp"

Comment: Are you running your application from an IDE? If so which one are you using?

Comment: From Qt Docs: If the file does not exist or is of an unknown format, the pixmap becomes a null pixmap.

Comment: Just to make sure that there's no problem with the filepath I would try using the absolute filepath to load the image. If that works then your working directory is not what you think it is. If it doesn't work then there's a problem with the file.

Comment: Yeah, you have right, with the absolute filepath, the pixmap is not null, but the image still doesn't print.

Comment: Could you try passing the pixmap into the constructor of QBrush instead of using brush->setTexture.

Comment: Still the same, i will edit with an imaghe example of what i have.

Comment: Okay, my bad, the image is printed but is to big, so can i set to fill the cell ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92997/discussion-between-mohamad-elghawi-and-raphael-teyssandier).